# Does Rust have an equivalent to Haskell's `sequence` function?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I am mapping over `Vec` such that each item becomes a `Result`. If any element is an `Err` then I want to terminate early and produce an `Err`, otherwise I want to produce an `Ok` containing the `Vec<i32>`.

```
let v = (1..10)
        .map( |n| {
            if n % 4 == 0 {
                Err("Too fourish!")
            }
            else {
                Ok(n)
            }
        }).collect::<Vec<_>>();


println!("{:?}", v);
```

In Haskell, I can use `sequence`. Is there an equivalent built-in Rust function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `FromIterator` implementation of `Result` for this:

```
fn main() {
    let v = (1..10)
        .map( |n| {
            if n % 4 == 0 {
                Err("Too fourish!")
            }
            else {
                Ok(n)
            }
        }).collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>();
    println!("{:?}", v);

    let v = (1..10)
        .map( |n| {
            if n % 4 == 4 { // impossible
                Err("Too fourish!")
            }
            else {
                Ok(n)
            }
        }).collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>();
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

Output:

```
Err("Too fourish!")
Ok([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

More info: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#implementations

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the `sequence` function in Haskell; does this replace every usage of `sequence` that a user would want?

Comment: @Shepmaster, [`sequence`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence) is generic over any monad, so `collect` isn't an automatic/guaranteed replacement due to Rust's lack of a generic monad, but I believe any type that could implement a hypothetical `Monad` trait can implement `FromIterator` in this way manually to ensure the trick works (e.g. `Option` does too).

Comment: (Also, the lack of laziness in Rust means the precise semantics are somewhat different.)